# PDFTron iOS and Android how to open the PdfViewCtrl at a specific page?

Tags: android, ios, pdftron

We are using the PDFTron SDK to read PDFs in our Xamarin app.
What we want to do is open the PDF at a specific page, since we want our users to continue reading where they left on our website.

We are following the example [found here](https://github.com/PDFTron/xamarin-forms-sample), with the `PTTabbedDocumentViewController` on iOS. Here is what we tried, to make this work.

```
        PDFDoc pdfDoc = TypeConvertHelper.ConvPdfDocToManaged(mTabViewController.SelectedViewController.PdfViewCtrl.GetDoc());
        if (pdfDoc != null)
        {
            var pageCount = pdfDoc.GetPageCount();
        }
```

But, the pdfDoc instance is always null. Please, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

**Android**

There is a method to start the viewer on a specific page:
https://www.pdftron.com/api/xamarinandroid/pdfnet/api/pdftronprivate.PDF.PDFViewCtrl.html#pdftronprivate_PDF_PDFViewCtrl_CurrentPage:
​

Here is a code sample:

```
        var myPage = 3;

        mPdfViewCtrl.DocumentLoad += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // On document loaded, set the page
            mPdfViewCtrl.CurrentPage = myPage;
        };
```

**iOS:**

For iOS the equivalent method is this:
https://www.pdftron.com/api/xamarinios/tools/api/pdftron.PDF.PTPDFViewCtrl.html#pdftron_PDF_PTPDFViewCtrl_SetCurrentPage_System_Int32_

```
mPdfViewCtrl.OnSetDoc += (sender, e) =>
{
    mPdfViewCtrl.SetCurrentPage(3);
};
```